# Configuring Reporting Task in Kylo

Tags: kylo

I am trying to configure reporting task in Nifi to be used by Kylo.I could not find Kylo reporting task in list.

[image]

I see following list of jars in Nifi lib.

[image]

Any pointers ?

Comment: Have you restarted Nifi since updating the nars?

Comment: And is this best asked on google groups? https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/kylo-community

Comment: @RuslansUralovs - I did restart nifi but no success.

Comment: Can you post nifi-app.log which shows nifi start sequence please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another instance of Nifi running in background which was causing issue. Looks like when I stopped Nifi for upgrade , somehow it was still running. I killed that process and restarted NiFi again and it worked.

Comment: Which URL did you use to open the nifi?+